# DocFX (VB.net) - Support for Inline Comments

Tags: vb.net, docfx

I am currently evaluating alternative solutions to producing API Documentation for our customers. Currently we use our own home-brewed solution, and I started some research. This was when I came across DocFX developed and used by Microsoft.

Seemed very useful, except for the fact there was nowhere I could see mentioning about including inline comments, such as the following example:

```
Enum Test
Value1= 0 ' This is a sample comment
End Enum
```

The reason for requiring this, particularly with enums is this is how we have been putting our comments we want to be publicly visible within the Documentation.

Comment: Inline comments are not extracted by the metadata generator of Microsoft, so docfx will never be able to pick them up.  Apparently Doxygen can do it, but I haven't tested it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
''' <summary>
''' egg size enum
''' </summary>
Public Enum EggSizeEnum
    ''' <summary>
    ''' jumbo
    ''' </summary>
    Jumbo
    ''' <summary>
    ''' extra large
    ''' </summary>
    ExtraLarge
    Large
    Medium
    Small
End Enum
```